# Cannot find hard disk after installing Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, system-installation, windows-10

I had Windows 10 installed on my PC then I created a new volume from C drive and then installed Ubuntu from live environment.

It said installations successful and everything OK. But after restart no Windows options were found in Grub menu. So I shut down by pressing switch. Then when I restarted PC it booted in Windows. And then I couldn't find the hard disk on PC.

I went to device manager found the disk but it was not showing anything may be unallocated. I tried to assign letter or anything else,  but no option was available.

Comment: Windows is not able to read Linux filesystems, so this is absolutely normal and expected behaviour

Comment: Kev is right. Get into Ubuntu, open GParted and you will see ALL partitions (windows + linux). Might be a little shocked at first, and you may discover hidden Windows partitions (like EFI, reserved or recovery). That's normal, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: so... now only thing I need to do is fix my grub installer right?

Answer (score 0):

Windows tools can't read Linux filesystems as Kev says.  Your next step, as you guessed, is to fix GRUB.  There's a dandy tool called "Boot Repair" that is designed to fix such problems.  Here's a [How-To Geek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/) about how to use it, and here's [the official Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).  Good luck, and let us know how it goes in the comments!

Comment: thnx guys.. fixed it already